# How to configure vs code prettier extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have configured the HTML `prettier.printWidth": 200`, but its still breaking the buttons like below

```html
<div classNameName="col-lg-12 text-center my-3 btn-group-div" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <div className="btn-group mx-auto" role="group">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={() => {
              setmyorders(myorders + 1);
            }}>
            Incr
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={() => {
              myorders > 0 ? setmyorders(myorders - 1) : setmyorders(0);
            }}>
            Decr
          </button>
        </div>
```

May I know how to configure VS code to stop splitting button in different line

I am expecting it to be like this:

```html
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => { myorders > 0 ? setmyorders(myorders - 1) : setmyorders(0);}}>Decr</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is not doing that, Prettier is. The whole purpose of Prettier is to make your code... well, *more pretty*, in an opinionated way, as they say. This means that there are very few options allowing you to tell it how to format your code, because the point is that Prettier is defining the format so everyone in the team follows the same rules, making merges easier and minimizing discussions about code style.
The "Print width" option tells Prettier what is the "generally preferred" line length. The button attributes are not in one line each because the line is to small; instead, it is because this is the style Prettier enforces for attributes. See these links:

- https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width
- https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-line

If you want full control about how you format your code, maybe Prettier is not what you should be using. Regarding your specific question, maybe this could help:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting

In particular, check `html.format.wrapAttributes` option, as well as `html.format.wrapLineLength`.